# Am I not ready to fight Alduin?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The game sent me up in the sky in order to go kill him, but I can’t even reach him without dying. I’ve also tried just running past all the other Dragons and skeleton Draugr thingys. I’m only level 13, and I feel like I’m not ready, but the game is like GO!!!! Fulfill your destiny as the DRAGONBORN. I don’t want to quit, but I don’t know what to do. It keeps saying I have to do this quest next, but I can’t do it.

Comment: You have to do the main quest all a once. You can go do side quest, the NPCs will wait for you.